# Передать объект функции с аргументами

Tags: python, функции, объекты, аргументы

Стоит такая задача: необходимо передать функцию, как объект, при этом, что б объект сразу нес в себе определенные данные. Для примера:

```
def print_smth1(a):
    print(a)

def print_smth2(a, b):
    print(a, b)

actions = {1: print_smth1, 
           2: print_smth2}

s = 1
action = actions.get(s)
action("text")
```

> text

Проблема в том, что я не хочу передавать в action() аргументы. Нужно реализовать, что-то наподобие:

```
def print_smth1(a):
    print(a)

def print_smth2(a, b):
    print(a, b)

actions = {1: print_smth1("text"),
           2: print_smth2("text1", "text2")}

s = 1
action = actions.get(s)
action()
```

Ожидаемый вывод

> text

Возможно ли провернуть такое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишете волшебное слово `lambda` и всё работает как вы хотите:

```
actions = {1: lambda: print_smth1("text"),
           2: lambda: print_smth2("text1", "text2")}
```

`lambda` создаёт "анонимную функцию", выполняющую указанный после неё код. Таким образом, вы получаете из словаря ссылку на нужную вам "анонимную функцию" и можете выполнить её как обычную функцию без аргументов. А вообще у `lambda` могут быть и свои аргументы, но в данном случае это не нужно.

Answer (score 4):

Для расширения ассортимента: можно воспользоваться partial из functools

```
from functools import partial

def print_smth1(a):
    print(a)

def print_smth2(a, b):
    print(a, b)

actions = {1: partial(print_smth1, 'text'),
           2: partial(print_smth2, 'text', 'text2')}

s = 1
action = actions.get(s)
action()
```

Answer (score 0):

еще, не самый удачный, но как вариант, можно декораторами воспользоваться

```
def arg_save(*args, **kwargs):
    def dec(func):
        def wrap():
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap
    return dec

def qwe(x):
    print(x + 1)

q = arg_save(2)(qwe)
q()  # 3
q()  # 3
```